# Asymmetric Time Dilation: Why Do They Teach It?

Tags: special-relativity, time-dilation

Brian Greene: The moving clock is slow, the stationary one is fast:

https://youtu.be/Q1y3YnPgaY4?t=1157

This is obviously non sequitur in special relativity (Einstein's 1905 postulates do not entail such an asymmetry) and yet Einstein himself used to teach it.

It follows logically from Einstein's 1905 postulates that, if two clocks are in relative motion, either clock is slower than the other as judged from the other clock's system, or either clock is faster than the other as judged from the clock's own system (SYMMETRIC time dilation). Then why do physicists (Einstein included) abuse logic and teach the non sequitur? Because symmetric time dilation (the valid deduction) doesn't, but asymmetric time dilation (the non sequitur) does imply time travel into the future?

"The paradigm of the special relativistic upheaval of the usual concept of time is the twin paradox. Let us emphasize that this striking example of time dilation proves that time travel (towards the future) is possible. As a gedanken experiment (if we neglect practicalities such as the technology needed for reaching velocities comparable to the velocity of light, the cost of the fuel and the capacity of the traveller to sustain high accelerations), it shows that a sentient being can jump, "within a minute" (of his experienced time) arbitrarily far in the future, say sixty million years ahead, and see, and be part of, what (will) happen then on Earth. This is a clear way of realizing that the future "already exists" (as we can experience it "in a minute")." http://www.bourbaphy.fr/damourtemps.pdf

Comment: From what I understand, these examples just assume that one of the frames in question is *your* rest frame, it's easier to explain something like this to an audience of laymen. Seems more like a pedagogical tool, rather than a non sequitur. Shifting between frames is only likely to confuse people who are just being introduced to the subject. What *does* seem like a non sequitur is the last paragraph. "Jumping" from one inertial frame to another means that you necessarily accelerate, and time flows very differently for you when this happens.

Comment: Also, to clarify: just by existing, we are all engaged in *time travel (towards the future)*.

Answer (score 2):

"Moving" is a symmetric concept. If you're moving in my frame, then I'm moving in your frame. So saying that "the moving frame is slower" automatically implies symmetry: in my frame you're moving, so you're slower. In your frame, I'm moving, so I'm slower.

"Accelerating" is not a symmetric concept. Accelerating frames are not on the same footing as inertial ones, and we can always tell from any frame wether that frame is accelerating or not, for instance by taking an object with you, holding on to it, and then letting it go: if you're accelerating, then the object will fly away from you, unless the same force that is accelerating you is still acting on it (like in a gravitational field). In the twin paradox, one of the two twins has to turn back to meet the other, which involves acceleration, an asymmetric situation. So it's not that weird to see an asymmetry between the twins at the end.